# Can I hook up my old TP-link router with a LAN cable instead of a phone cable?

Tags: internet, lan, modem

So I have a TD-W8960N Version 1 modem (router) from 2007. It has a phone line jack and 4 LAN jacks. Years ago I used to connect the modem to the wall phone cable line (using ADSL-splitters and such). However, in my dorm room there is only a LAN wall outlet. Is it possible to re-route the connection as follows: Internet Provider ----> wall ------LAN cable-----> Modem LAN input jack number 1 ->->-> another LAN cable out of jack number 2-------> Computer ?

The instructions on the TP-link website were limited. Excuse me if the wording is confusing. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So you want to make this ADSL modem/router just a simple router? Unfortunately, no you can't... The "WAN port" is hard coded to the ADSL modem port. Sorry. If you just want to make it a simple switch, log in and disable DHCP, and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I googled your router. Yes, connecting to port 1 is where the Isp connects. You will need to set up the router to identify port 1 as the Isp . I recommend downloading the manual for setup if per chance you have misplaced it.
Do note however that the speed of your router is 100 mbps maximum on a wired connection . Not 1000 mbps which newer routers are capable of.